# Using IndexOf in ComboBoxCell.Items collection throws an exception in case-insensitive comparisons

Tags: vb.net, indexof, case-insensitive, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I didn't find any good solution for my issue. A bit of explanations. I have DataGridView with a few Columns. In the first Column, the cell shows the path to some file. Starting from the third Column, I have couple of ComboBoxCells.

In the DropDown of the ComboBoxes, I wish to make auto-select equal (case insensitive) values to the part of the File path in the first cell. All this happens on `Form.Load`.
Later, users make their own choices.

```
Dim CmbCell As DataGridViewComboBoxCell = CType(DgvRow.Cells(2), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)
Dim ResultString As String
If HasDropDownThisValue(DgvRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString, CmbCell, ResultString) Then
    CmbCell.Value = CmbCell.Items(CmbCell.Items.IndexOf(ResultString))
End If
```

This is the method used in the `If` statement:

```
Private Function HasDropDownThisValue(ByVal GivenValue As String, ByRef comboCeel As DataGridViewComboBoxCell, ByRef ReturnValue As String) As Boolean
    ReturnValue = ""
    Dim boolret As Boolean = False
    Dim comparestring As String
    Dim StringArr() As String = Split(GivenValue, CStr(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar), -1, VisualBasic.CompareMethod.Text)
    comparestring = StringArr(0)
    For i As Integer = 1 To UBound(StringArr)

        If comboCeel.Items.Cast(Of String).Contains(comparestring, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then
            ReturnValue = comparestring
            boolret = True
            Exit For
        Else
            comparestring = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", comparestring, Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, StringArr(i))
        End If
    Next
    Return boolret
End Function
```

The line:

```
CmbCell.Value = CmbCell.Items(CmbCell.Items.IndexOf(ResultString))
```

throws an exception when the case doesn't match. How to avoid that?
I probably can do something like: `CmbCell.Value = ResultString`, but I prefer to pre-define values in Items collection.

Maybe something like this is possible (used in a function):

```
comboCeel.Items.Cast(Of String).Contains(comparestring, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need a case-insensitive match, you can use [IndexOf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof), with the [StringComparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison) option set to `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase`, to find a string value in the `DataGridViewComboBoxCell.ObjectCollection` (which represents a collection of strings, in this case).

I suggest to set `Dim ResultString As String = Nothing` and not to reset it to `String.Empty` (`""`) in the `HasDropDownThisValue` method: if the method returns `False`, you then set `[ComboBoxCell].Value = ResultString` (which is `Nothing`), so the ComboBox selection is cleared.
Otherwise, use `IndexOf()` to find a matching string in the collection. Still, if no match is found, the resulting value will be `Nothing`, so the ComboBox is cleared; otherwise set the value found:

<sub>(local variables renamed to comply with standard naming conventions)</sub>

```
Dim resultString As String = Nothing
Dim cmbCell = CType(DgvRow.Cells(2), DataGridViewComboBoxCell)

If HasDropDownThisValue(DgvRow.Cells(0).Value?.ToString(), cmbCell, resultString) Then
    resultString = cmbCell.Items.OfType(Of String).
        FirstOrDefault(Function(i) i.IndexOf(resultString, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
End If
cmbCell.Value = resultString
```

As you can see, passing `resultString` as reference becomes quite useless. You can change your method to return a String instead of a Boolean, since we need to use that string anyway (no matter whether `HasDropDownThisValue` finds a match or not).

Also, you shouldn't pass the ComboBox Cell `ByRef`: this object is already a Reference Type, you should pass it `ByVal` (or don't specify the modifier, since `ByVal` is the default).

Comment: It is working as I expected, but later i found another issue. When I compare string e.g. "plate", and in the cell items contains "aluminium plate" and "plate"... It chooses "aluminium plate".